# How to return the receiver from a method in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, oop

I know that I can return a method's name using `__method__`:

```
def foo    
  __method__
end
```

But how do I return the **object** the method is attached to? For example:

```
class Integer
  def foo
    # code
  end
end

1.foo
#=> 1
```

Comment: Just return `self`

Comment: Note that `Fixnum` is deprecated – it's all `Integer` now.

Comment: If the only thing your method does is to return self, you might consider not calling any method at all : `"1 # => 1"`

Comment: I need this value for calculations in method`s body. Thanks, guys, rly stupid question =(

Comment: @zOs0 a rule of thumb: don't monkey-patch Ruby's core classes (or classes you don't own in general). It might seem elegant at first but often causes a lot of pain in the long run.

Comment: It's indeed a really basic question, but I'm upvoting it anyway. I can neither find a duplicate nor a good example in Ruby's documentation. BTW, if you need this for calculations, you could change your example to return something like `self * 2`.

Comment: Adding a method to return `self` has been superfluous for a while, you can use `Kernel#itself` instead (see my answer below). The related discussion is here: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/6373#change-28682 (I was the person who originally made the PR against Facets that trans mentions in the description).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`self` refers to the object itself:

```
class Fixnum
  def foo
    self
  end
end
```